# "I got exception error in flutter project"

Tags: exception

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Caught exception: Couldn't start watching, error = 1: E:\atomicdex\atomicdex-mobile-master\android
Note: C:\Users\Audio\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\git\dargon2-d11f51cab560acf7644ebef402f1996b6f320365\dargon2_flutter\dargon2_flutter_mobile\android\src\main\java\com\tejasmehta\dargon2_flutter\Dargon2FlutterPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Audio\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\local_auth-1.1.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\localauth\LocalAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.

> Build command failed.
> Error while executing process C:\Users\Audio\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\ninja.exe with arguments {-C E:\atomicdex\atomicdex-mobile-master\android\app.cxx\Debug\2c2c1l6u\arm64-v8a mm2-lib}
> ninja: Entering directory `E:\atomicdex\atomicdex-mobile-master\android\app.cxx\Debug\2c2c1l6u\arm64-v8a'

ninja: error: 'E:/atomicdex/atomicdex-mobile-master/android/app/src/main/cpp/libs/arm64-v8a/libmm2.a', needed by 'E:/atomicdex/atomicdex-mobile-master/build/app/intermediates/cxx/Debug/2c2c1l6u/obj/arm64-v8a/libmm2-lib.so', missing and no known rule to make it

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried flutter 3.10 and then get null safety error and when I use flutter 3.7 I got this error